# JSON-LD Frame: Forcing duplication of redundant properties values

Tags: parsing, json-ld

Is it possible to force the duplication of redundant properties values, such as `author` and `creator`?

The goal is to reduce later extra parsing and to have an easy-to-walk JSON object, no matter the duplicated values.

The sample:

```json
{
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "articleBody": "Article Body",
  "author": {
    "id": "_:b1"
  },
  "creator": {
    "id": "_:b1",
    "type": "Person",
    "name": "Creator Name",
    "url": "https://example.org/author/creator-name/"
  },
  "description": "Description.",
  "headline": "Headline"
}
```

The frame:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.json",
  "@vocab": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": ["Article", "NewsArticle", "TechArticle", "ScholarlyArticle"],
  "author": {
    "@type": "http://schema.org/Person",
    "@embed": "true"
  }
}
```

The expected result:

```json
{
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "articleBody": "Article Body",
    "author": {
      "id": "_:b1",
      "type": "Person",
      "name": "Creator Name",
      "url": "https://example.org/author/creator-name/"
    },
    "creator": {
      "id": "_:b1",
      "type": "Person",
      "name": "Creator Name",
      "url": "https://example.org/author/creator-name/"
    },
    "description": "Description.",
    "headline": "Headline"
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a node repeated, you want to use `"@embed": "@always"`. Try [this update to your example on the JSON-LD Playground](https://json-ld.org/playground-dev/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fdocs%2Fjsonldcontext.json%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22NewsArticle%22%2C%22articleBody%22%3A%22Article%20Body%22%2C%22author%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22_%3Ab1%22%7D%2C%22creator%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22_%3Ab1%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22Person%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Creator%20Name%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fauthor%2Fcreator-name%2F%22%7D%2C%22description%22%3A%22Description.%22%2C%22headline%22%3A%22Headline%22%7D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fdocs%2Fjsonldcontext.json%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%5B%22Article%22%2C%22NewsArticle%22%2C%22TechArticle%22%2C%22ScholarlyArticle%22%5D%2C%22author%22%3A%7B%22%40embed%22%3A%22%40always%22%7D%2C%22creator%22%3A%7B%22%40embed%22%3A%22%40always%22%7D%7D&context=%7B%7D).

Input:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.json",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "articleBody": "Article Body",
  "author": {
    "id": "_:b1"
  },
  "creator": {
    "id": "_:b1",
    "type": "Person",
    "name": "Creator Name",
    "url": "https://example.org/author/creator-name/"
  },
  "description": "Description.",
  "headline": "Headline"
}
```

Frame:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.json",
  "@type": ["Article", "NewsArticle", "TechArticle", "ScholarlyArticle"],
  "author": {
    "@embed": "@always"
  },
  "creator": {
    "@embed": "@always"
  }
}
```

Result:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.json",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "type": "NewsArticle",
      "articleBody": "Article Body",
      "author": {
        "id": "_:b1",
        "type": "Person",
        "name": "Creator Name",
        "url": "https://example.org/author/creator-name/"
      },
      "creator": {
        "id": "_:b1",
        "type": "Person",
        "name": "Creator Name",
        "url": "https://example.org/author/creator-name/"
      },
      "description": "Description.",
      "headline": "Headline"
    }
  ]
}
```